# How to get the actual HTTP request from a model in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would need to get the actual Request from a model in rails 3. I know there is not always an request processed, but if there is one I would like to be able to access it. How is it possible to reach. In case of controllers, the request method is in place. But now I need to access the request from a bit "lower level". Can you give me any clues how to do it in Rails?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can store the request in the thread, and then access it anywhere.
This is def a hack as you really should not break the MVC convention this way, and if a model is really request dependent you could always pass the request to the model as a parameter.

but the hack to make your request available everywhere would be for application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :store_request_in_thread

def store_request_in_thread
  Thread.current[:request] = request
end
```

and in your model  somemodel.rb or really anywhere you expect request to already exist, you can just access the request:

```
def something
  request = Thread.current[:request]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it might be a bit hackie, but at the moment I do not see other way to make ActiveRecord behave differently based on the domain name where the request comes from. I am thinking about catching and storing the current request in the middleware.